# advantage and disadvantage of Tomcat clustering

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, cluster-computing, ehcache

Currently we have same web application deployed on 4 different tomcat instances, each one running on independent machine. A load Balancer distribute requests to these servers. Our web application makes database calls, maintain cache (key-value pairs). All tomcat instances read same data(XML) from same data-source(another server) and serve it to clients. In future, we are planning to collect some usage data from requests, process and store it in database. This functionality should be common(one module) between all tomcat servers.

Now we are thinking of using tomcat clustering. I done some research but I am not able to figure out how to separate data fetching operations i.e. reading same data(XML) from same data-source(another server) part from all tomcat web apps that make it common. So that once one server fetches data from server, it will maintain it (may be in cache) and the same data can be used by some other server to serve client. Now this functionality can be implemented using distributed cache. But there are other modules that can be made common in all other tomcat instances.

So basically, Is there any advantage of using Tomcat clustering? And if yes then how can I implement module which are common to all tomcat servers.

Comment: No answers!!!. This doesn't look like difficult question (or is it?!!!). Someone please let me know if I am missing something like adding proper tag or description is not clear etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read Tomcat [configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/cluster.html) and [clustering guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). Available clustering features are as follows:

> The tomcat cluster implementation provides session replication,
>   context attribute replication and cluster wide WAR file deployment.

So, by clustering, you'll gain:

- **High availability**: when one node fails, another will be able to take over without losing access to the data. For example, a HTTP session can still be handled without the user noticing the error.
- **Farm deployment**: you can deploy your .war to a single node, and the rest will synchronize automatically.

The costs are mainly in performance:

- Replication implies object **serialization** between the nodes. This may be undesired in some cases, but it's also possible to [fine tune](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Overview).

If you just want to share some state between the nodes, then you don't need clustering at all (unless you're going to use context or session replication). Just use a database and/or a distributed cache model like ehcache (or anything else).